# Retry failed Google Drive API batch

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to handle failed batch request over Google Drive API v2 using the [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors) approach, but when it executes again the batch using `batch.execute();`, it fails due to the batch being empty. I would prefer not to rebuild the batch from scratch due to the workflow required. Is there any workaround?

Edit:

If I try to relaunch the batch without rebuilding it from scratch, I get an `IllegalStateException`, which is caused by the batch being empty (which it wasn't first time it was launched). Below there's copy of the stack trace.

`com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:161)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:217)
    at com.nubbius.server.drive.DriveServiceImpl.importarFicheros(DriveServiceImpl.java:3647)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 42 more`

Comment: I checked the [Drive Handling Errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors). That(exponential backoffs) seems to be the available option as of now.

What error log are you getting?

Comment: Hi noogui, thanks for your reply. I updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Having the same problem.